# Swift: Get current class from a static method

Tags: swift, static, self

In Swift, let's say I want to add a static factory method that returns an instance:

```
class MyClass {
  static func getInstance() {
    return MyClass(someProperty);
  }
}
```

But what if I don't want to write the class name? Is there an equivalent of `self` but for static methods and properties?

Same idea if I want to call another static method from a static method:

```
class MyClass {
  static func prepare(){
    //Something
  }

  static func doIt() {
    MyClass.prepare();
  }
}
```

Can I do this without using `MyClass` explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

self works in static methods too, like this:

```
class MyClass {
  static func prepare(){
    print("Hello");
  }

  static func doIt() {
    self.prepare();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about `self()`? I get some errors saying I need `self.init`, and when I do I get some other error that I need a `required` initializer...

Comment: self() is not possible, but I'm wondering why do you want to do that? dfri describes the best practice above to create Factory design pattern. Here's another sample: https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift/blob/master/source/creational/factory.swift

Comment: The only reason I'm doing this is because the code will be copy pasted and distributed for other people to use. I thought the least things hard-coded the better... Thanks!

Comment: Then I recommend to use a base protocol and swift generics (details in post)

Answer (score 0):

As RobberR writes above, you could just use `self` for accessing static function of `self`, and `self.init(...)` for your factory example. Note that you still must specify `MyClass` as return type in your factory method.

As an alternative, more generic approach, you could let your class conform to a factory protocol which contains a default implementation for the factory method. With this, the static factory method isn't tied to any specific class, but can however be *accessed* by any class conforming to the factory protocol (and an additional help protocol for common initializers).

Factory setup:

```
protocol FactoryInitializers {
    var commonProperty : Int { get set }
    init(commonProperty: Int)
}

protocol FactoryMethods {
    typealias T: FactoryInitializers
    static var defaultStaticCommonProperty : Int { get }
}
extension FactoryMethods {
    static func getInstance() -> T {
        return T(commonProperty: defaultStaticCommonProperty)
    }
    static func getInstanceFor(commonProperty commonProperty: Int) -> T {
        return T(commonProperty: commonProperty)
    }
}

protocol Factory : FactoryMethods, FactoryInitializers { }
```

Example class conformances:

```
class MyClass : Factory {
    typealias T = MyClass
    static var defaultStaticCommonProperty : Int = 1

    var commonProperty : Int = 0

    required init(commonProperty: Int) {
        self.commonProperty = commonProperty
    }
}

class MyOtherClass : Factory {
    typealias T = MyOtherClass
    static var defaultStaticCommonProperty : Int = 10

    var commonProperty : Int = 0

    required init(commonProperty: Int) {
        self.commonProperty = commonProperty
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var foo = MyClass.getInstance()
print(foo.dynamicType)    // "MyClass"
print(foo.commonProperty) // 1
foo = MyClass.getInstanceFor(commonProperty: 5)
print(foo.commonProperty) // 5

var bar = MyOtherClass.getInstance()
print(bar.dynamicType)    // "MyOtherClass"
print(bar.commonProperty) // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Protocol and use the [swift generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) like this:

```
protocol Vehicle {
  init()
}

class MyVehicleFactory<T:Vehicle> {
  static func getInstance() -> T {
    return T()
  }
}
```

And the people who copied your code can do this:

```
class Car : Vehicle {
  required init() { }
}
let car = MyVehicleFactory<Car>.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a factory method that doesn't reference the class, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static func factory() -> Self {
        let instance = Self.init()
        // other init here
        return instance
    }
}
```